# Kinect how to get accurate bone information?

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

I'm working on a unity project in which I use Kinect to fetch movements. I use a plugin called `unity kinect1.7 wrapper` to communicate with Kinect and generally it works fine.

However, when I put my right hand in front of my left shoulder(right_hand.x == left_shoulder.x and right_hand.y > left_shoulder.y), weird thing happened. The x position of my left shoulder changed very fast(between -0.2 ~-0.4), but I didn't move my left shoulder. Looks like the data of the left shoulder had been interfered by my right hand.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: This is a limitation on the Kinect hardware.  Self occlusion isn't something that can be fixed. Best bet, use joints you think are good to infer the position of one that isn't.  Defining a "good" joint is not trivial though.